# An injection from $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{Z^{+})}$ to $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{ N \times N)}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I am thinking about how to prove that $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{ N \times N)}$ – the power set of $ \mathbb{N \times N}$  – is not countable. My idea was to show the existence of an injection  $f: \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{Z^{+})}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{ N \times N)}$, and then, supposing $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{ N \times N)}$ were countable, there would also exist an injection from it to $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$, and so, the composition $f \circ g: f: \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{Z^{+})}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$ would also be injective, contradicting Cantor's theorem. I thought this was pretty neat, but I've slowed down trying to think about whether there could be such an injection or not. I wonder if anyone can help me think about how to think about whether such an injection – from the power set of $ \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ to the power set of  $ \mathbb{N \times N}$ – would be possible or not?

Comment: If you know $\mathscr{P}({\mathbb{Z}^{+}})$ is not countable, then trivially $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N})$ is not countable.

Comment: What's the difference between $\mathbb Z^+$ and $\mathbb N$ here? If $\mathbb Z^+ = \mathbb N$, then just use the injection $\{x\}_x \mapsto \{(x, 1)\}_x$.

Comment: I should have said. $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$ in that way I'm setting things up, so $\mathbb{N} \neq \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

Comment: @Nakayama you're using 'trivial' a bit loosely here.

Comment: If $A \subseteq B$, then $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$ proves it trivially. As $\mathbb{N} \times \{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, and the first is in bijection with $\mathbb{Z}^+$, the result follows. I think that this is what @Nakayama meant.

Comment: Furthermore, $\mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{N}, (n, m) \mapsto 2^n3^m$ is an injection, from which follows that $|\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{Z}^+|$, and it follows that $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb
{N} \times \mathbb
N)| = |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}^+)|$.

Comment: The latter comment assumes Cantor-Bernstein-Schröeder

Comment: Do this last comment also assume the unique factorization theorem? @user480840

Comment: yes, @DanÖz, it does assume it.

Comment: Still, the simple function already mentioned, $\{x\}_x \mapsto \{(x,1)\}_x$ is enough. It's clearly not surjective, but why get any fancier?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z^+} \neq \mathbb{N}$ remember. I think that suggestion was for if it did